# How to get all namespaces inside a namespace recursively

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, namespaces

To put it simple, I want all the namespaces in the project recursively, and classes available  in all namespaces found earlier.

```
var namespaces = assembly.GetTypes()
                  .Select(ns => ns.Namespace);
```

I am using this part earlier to get the namespaces in string format.
But now i got to know the underlying namespaces as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you *might* want a `Lookup` from namespace to class:

```
var lookup = assembly.GetTypes().ToLookup(t => t.Namespace);
```

Or alternatively (and very similarly) you could use `GroupBy`:

```
var groups = assembly.GetTypes().GroupBy(t => t.Namespace);
```

For example:

```
var groups = assembly.GetTypes()
                     .Where(t => t.IsClass) // Only include classes
                     .GroupBy(t => t.Namespace);
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Namespace: {0}", group.Key);
    foreach (var type in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}", t.Name);
    }
}
```

However, it's not entirely clear whether that's what you're after. That will get you the classes in each namespace, but I don't know whether that's really what you're looking for.

Two points to bear in mind:

- There's nothing recursive about this
- Namespaces don't *really* form a hierarchy, as far as the CLR is concerned. There's no such thing as an "underlying" namespace. The C# language itself *does* have some rules about this, but as far as the CLR is concerned, there's no such thing as a "parent" namespace.

If you *really* want to go from "Foo.Bar.Baz" to "Foo.Bar" and "Foo" then you can use something like:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ns);
    int index = ns.LastIndexOf('.');
    if (index == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
    ns = ns.Substring(0, index);
}
```

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thank you so much. Especially your knowledge on .Net is great. I would like to be a student of yours. :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I also want to know more about Reflection. I underestimated Reflection earlier. So I want to know more about this. Is there any way i can get most of the experimental knowledge on this topic. I know one method, trying. :) If there is any source, please suggest me.

Comment: @Prakash: Trying is a really good option when it comes to reflection, to be honest. Have a look at all the members of things like Type and MethodInfo, and think of places where they could be useful.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The code you gave should be updated to give out only classes. right now it gives all the types in the namespace including interfaces, enum, structure. And how to filter abstract classes from the class..?

Comment: @Prakash: Just use a "Where" call in the LINQ query e.g. using Type.IsClass. I'll edit the answer for that one; for other conditions you'd just adjust that condition.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: If I want to carry a list of namespaces over many methods, should I use the type `System.Linq.Lookup<string, Type>` or is there a way to identify the namespace with just a string.?

Comment: @Prakash: It's not really clear what you mean. Yes, a string will just identify the namespace - but that won't give you all the types within the namespace...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Its like, I am using a TreeView to display the Namespaces. When you click to expand('+'), basing on the selected namespace I want to load the classes. When a class is clicked to expand, the respective methods get loaded. I was not able to find the type of the selected node.

Comment: @Prakash: Well it's hard to know what's going wrong in that case... but it sounds like it would be worth caching the types rather than having to look through the whole assembly every time the node is expanded.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: How to find the type of the selectedNode. whether it is a class or namespace.?

Comment: @Prakash: That will really depend on the rest of your code... and is quite a long way from the subject of this question. I suggest you ask a new question with some sample code.